# Errors when loading ci-merchant library

Tags: ci-merchant

I'm trying to use http://ci-merchant.org/ for CodeIgniter. But when I load the merchant library, I get these errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> Filename: libraries/merchant.php
>
> Line Number: 97
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> Filename: libraries/merchant.php
>
> Line Number: 103

Here is my code:

```
$this->load->library('merchant');
$this->merchant->load('paypal_express');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source of that file](https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/blob/master/libraries/merchant.php#L97), the driver name needs to be passed as a string. So I highly doubt the two lines of code you put above is actually what's being called, it looks like you are passing an array as the driver name.

If you aren't sure where it's coming from, try adding some `debug_print_backtrace()` lines to the merchant.php file to figure out where the array is getting passed from.

Comment: For some reason, renaming the file application/config/merchant.php solved my problem. It seems that $this->merchant->load('paypal_express'); is not actually passing 'paypal_express' but the config items I put application/config/merchant.php